# Make A Call In Objective-C To A Method Using Swift String

Tags: ios, objective-c, swift

I have a class method in Swift:

```
import Foundation

public class MyClass : NSObject{
    class func registerDevice(userId uId: String, deviceId dId: String, pushServiceToken token: String) -> Void{ /*...*? }
}
```

I'm then trying to call that function from Objective-C, but I'm borking something. Here's what I'm trying:

```
[MyClass registerDevice: @"user id" deviceId: [UIDevice currentDevice].identifierForVendor.UUIDString pushServiceToken: registrationToken];
```

...but I'm getting the error:

> "No known class method for selector 'registerDevice::deviceId:pushServiceToken:'"

What's the right way to make this call?

Comment: No, it is, because you use the wrong selector. This is the "method name", regardless of its parameter types. Likely you have to add `UserId` or so after `registerDevice`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find out how Xcode translates the Swift signature to Objective-C by checking the auto-generated `<module>-Swift.h` file.  `<module>` will be the name of the app, if you haven't defined a module (and/or you're not building a framework).

To find the file (it doesn't appear in your project sources), hit cmd-shift-O and enter **-Swift.h**.

EDIT: In this case, the method was named "registerDeviceWithUserId".

Comment: Great answer, not only for pointing me in the right direction, but also for the handy tip on the keyboard shortcut! It turns out, the function was renamed to "registerDeviceWithUserId".